# Texture from .png>dds

Tags: texturing, scripting, file-format

Is there anyone of you who knows if this question is maybe already answered.

All my textures in my .blend file are now .png is there any way i can change them from format with a little script to .dds so my export tool works correct for my game.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need to convert the files from png to dds fromat outside of blender; but you could write a script to find all of the png image files in your blend file and change the names to use the dds version.  [This exchange on BlenderArtist](https://blenderartists.org/t/changing-the-image-in-the-image-texture-node-via-python/618634) has an example of how to do it for a single image.

Comment: Okay i already have all the textures set as .dds and they are all in a folder.
but the textures linked to the objects are still .png and to change every texture manually from png>dds takes a lot off time so i whas wondering if there is a script what can do it for me quickly

Comment: Ok so i tested it and i still got an little bugg

I added an video to make it more clear 
https://streamable.com/htlr87

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have all of your dds files in the same folder (directory) and each png file has a dds file that has the same name with png changed to dds, this script should do what you want once you've changed the line to point to your dds files.

````py
import bpy

def find_nodes_by_type(material, node_type):
    """ Return a list of all of the nodes in the material
        that match the node type.
        Return an empty list if the material doesn't use
        nodes or doesn't have a tree.
    """
    node_list = []
    if material.use_nodes and material.node_tree:
            for n in material.node_tree.nodes:
                if n.type == node_type:
                    node_list.append(n)
    return node_list

path_to_dds_files = CHANGE_ME_TO_PATH_TO_DDS_FILES

for material in bpy.data.materials:
    texture_nodes = find_nodes_by_type(material, 'TEX_IMAGE')
    for texture in texture_nodes:
        if texture.image.name.endswith('.png'):
            new_name = texture.image.name.split(sep='.')[-2] + '.dds'
            new_image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath = path_to_dds_files + new_name)
            print(f"{material.name}: {texture.image.name}, {new_name}")
            texture.image = new_image
```
````

Comment: Thank you verry verry much